# Pass a linear gradient to a Sass mixin

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I would like to pass the entire linear-gradient to my mixin.
I've tried any way I could think of and it always results in it coming up 'none' which covers my image in white.

```
@mixin webp-backgroundGradient($imgpath, $type: '.jpg') {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 10%, white 80%), url('#{$imgpath}#{$type}');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work pretty good, see codepen...

https://codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/GRNegrP

I'm guessing its an issue with your image path maybe? Hard to tell with out seeing your console source.

I removed `$type: '.jpg'` from your mixin params and passed the image url directly.

```scss
@mixin webp-backgroundGradient($img) {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(white, 0.5) 10%,
      rgba(white, 1) 90%
    ),
    url("#{$img}");
}

.image {
  height: 100vh;
  @include webp-backgroundGradient("https://i.imgur.com/UNV29z8.jpeg");
}
```

And this is the output...

```css
.image {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 10%, white 90%), url("https://i.imgur.com/UNV29z8.jpeg");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="image"></div>
```

---

### Update to your comment...

`@mixin` to pass background image url and optional background gradient overlay...

See codepen example here https://codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/JjbzOoj

```scss
@mixin bg_img_gradient($img,$gradient:false) {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  @if $gradient != false {
    background-image: #{$gradient}, url("#{$img}");
  } @else {
    background-image: url("#{$img}");
  }
}

.image-1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width:50%;
  float: left;
  @include bg_img_gradient(
    "https://i.imgur.com/UNV29z8.jpeg"
  );
}

.image-2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width:50%;
  float: left;
  @include bg_img_gradient(
    "https://i.imgur.com/UNV29z8.jpeg",
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(white, 0.5) 10%,
      rgba(white, 1) 90%
    )
  );
}
```

And here is the `css` output...

```css
.image-1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/UNV29z8.jpeg");
}

.image-2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 10%, white 90%), url("https://i.imgur.com/UNV29z8.jpeg");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="image-1"></div>
<div class="image-2"></div>
```

Comment: I would like to pass in the gradient as a param like this:

'at'include webp-backgroundGradient("https://i.imgur.com/UNV29z8.jpeg", linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 10%, white 90%));

The idea is I want to dynamically set the gradient since different pics have different gradient or none at all.

Comment: @itshinkswhenitscold see updated answer, is this what you are after?

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks